# PHP simple file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm doing a simple file upload using the following script:

```
$errors = '';
$target_path = "[PATH HERE]";

$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
     $errors = "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
     $errors = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! Type: " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];
    }
```

For some reason, I get an error uploading the file and the file type is not displayed. It seems to only grab the name of the file without the extension (i.e. "test" rather than "test.pdf"). I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason people insist on never doing proper error checking.  Make sure that $_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] does not have an error, and then make sure your path is correct in move_uploaded_file and then if you still have problems, make sure the user the web server is running as has  write permissions on the directory.

Comment: And check that the `upload_max_filesize` php ini variable is big enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Upload_max_filesize is correct.
@Corbin $_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] isn't returning anything. I replaced the error with:
$errors = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! Error: " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['error'];
and nothing gets printed. var_dump is also just showing an array of 0 elements.

Comment: If files is a zero length array that means that the file is never even reaching PHP.  That implies your form is wrong, or Apache is killing it for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, had to set my form to have enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

If you check the error element in the files array, you'll probably find it's some value other than 0.  The error should be 0 if nothing went wrong.  Otherwise, compare the value stored in error against the PHP documentation to determine what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your entering the path wrong (ending slash), or php dont have permission to write to the directory.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Show some errors

$target_path = "/var/www/somesite.com/uploads/"; // Would require a ending slash 

$target_path = $target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    $errors = "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
    $errors = "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! Type: " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];
}

?>
```

Comment: I double checked the path, and the ending slash is there. I also checked permissions and they were correct as well.